# SSIS not able to restore deleted DataFlows

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SSIS. I come to situation where i accedently delete some of my dataflows from the package but now i am not able to restore it. someone can you tell me is there any way to restore deleted data flows .

I am using `Microsoft SQLserver 2008 r2 BIDS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the 2012 release of SSIS, undo was not a capability of the editor. People generally manage this through diligent use of version control software.